# The location for this project is already set to another value In firebase Storage console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage, firebase-console

I am trying to set Storage in the Firebase console. But when setting location it shows an error.

> The location for this project is already set to another value

[image]

**Edit:**
In setting, it shows location selected. In storage when enable, i do not have any option to choose stroage location as it shows nothing to choose and only option is to click on done, which shows error.
[image: Image of Setting in firebase console]

Comment: did you set location for firestore database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations):

> **Warning**: Setting the location for one of these services (that is, Cloud Firestore, **Cloud Storage**, or scheduled functions) also sets the location for the others. After you set your project's default GCP resource location, you cannot change it.

So once you have selected a location, there is no way you can change it. If you need another location, most likely you should create another project and use the other location.

Besides that, there is also mentioned that:

> For Cloud Storage, your default GCP resource location only applies to your default bucket. If you're on the Blaze plan, you can create multiple buckets, each with its own location.

Comment: I do not want to change location, but once i enable storage it goes through all these dialogs, as i am unable to stop these, i can not bypass it at all.

Comment: this error comes after done click

Comment: That means that you have already set the location, hence the error. Try to set the location correctly in the first place.

Comment: can you guide me to set location? as in dialog box there is no option and just need to press done button.

Comment: What is the Firebase product that are you setting first, Firebase Storage?

Comment: This project is old and first i have firebase firestore that was set, now i just wanted to enable storage.

Comment: When you set Firestore's location, when you created the project, Storage's location was also set by default. Storage's location, unfortunately, cannot be changed anymore.

Comment: did not work, I can not go further in storage as clicking on done button do not work at all

Comment: It sounds like your question started off about locations, but you're asking now something related to a button click. At this point, you should probably think about asking a new question that illustrates what's not working the way you expect. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: So can I help you with other information regarding the initial question which is related to location?

Comment: I think i will create new project, This error may be due to old project. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: You're very welcome, Shvet.

Answer (score 2):

It is at least mind-blowing how this question was misunderstood.

This is not about the fact that once you set the location for the Firestore database, that is also the location for the Firebase Storage. But that, somehow, in the second step of settings up the Firebase Storage, after you press 'Done', because you can't change the location and there is nothing for you to do, you see the error from OP's post: that the location is already set. And nothing else.

You can't finish setting up Firebase Storage.

I also encounter this bug. And even in the project settings the default location is not set. I try to set it, but it says the same: another source has selected the location for this project.

This is what I did: I enabled authentication and Firestore database on an old project - maybe 2 years old, it didn't had a default location. I select one.

After a few days, I want to set up the Firebase Storage also and I get the same error as OP.

I didn't had another option but to create a new project and setting the Firestore and Firebase Storage one after the other, without waiting for a couple of days.

In the correct scenario: you will see the error when you reached the second step and pressing done would actually create the Storage bitbucket.

We are dealing with a bug here. On pressing 'Done', Firebase console through this error:

```
   {
      "error": {
        "code": 409,
        "message": "Requested entity already exists",
        "status": "ALREADY_EXISTS"
      }
    }
```

Looks like it's trying to set the location again, but it's already settled. Although the project settings doesn't show any location.

Comment: This is what i am encoutering.